# Pythonic way to avoid creation of a new list when iterating over a slice?

Tags: python, python-2.x

Quite a common pattern is to walk over a part of a list and search/select/process the items:

```
for item in array[start:end]:
   # do something
```

As far as I know, this creates a new list from `array[start:end]` copying the items, walks over it, then the temporary list is garbage collected. This looks like a waste of CPU usage.

Using [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) solves this.

Question: why this is not used much and taught like are taught dangers of mutable default function arguments, etc.?

**UPDATE:**

As pointed out in the comments, "`itertools.islice` is for iterables, rather than lists. It has to iterate a bunch of times before reaching the nth element".

I guess `islice` isn't a good example, but **creation of a temporary list just to walk over it is an existing problem. Isn't it?**

You could do:

```
for i in xrange(start, end):
    item = array[i]
    # do something with the item
```

**Is there there a *pythonic* way to iterate over a part of a sequence without creating a copy of it?**. Because negative indexes in this example are not supported, and it's not so nice as `for item in sequence`.

Comment: Presumably because this level of understanding only comes when performance becomes an issue. When your code "just works", it can be argued that the slicing behaviour is fine.

Comment: `itertools.islice` is for iterables, rather than lists. It has to iterate a bunch of times before reaching the nth element.

Comment: This question may be interesting to you, but it is not suitable for the Stack Exchange Q&A format. The tradeoffs of `islice()` aren't all *that* black and white; creating a new list object with the indexes copied across *can* be faster than having to iterate through `start` entries first to get to the desired slice, for example.

Comment: Maybe `islice` isn't a good example, but creation of a temporary list just to walk over it is an existing problem. Is there an alternative?

Comment: You are welcome to join us in the [Python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) to discuss this kind of stuff; such *I wonder why* questions work far better in an interactive setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason slicing is Pythonic, even though it creates a copy, is because the cost of slicing is usually trivial in the grand scheme of things. If you slice 10,000 items from a `list`, just to iterate them and discard them, the cost of this is:

1. Allocating space for 10,000 pointers (40K - 80K bytes)
2. Copying over the pointers from source to new space
3. Incrementing the reference count of each pointer
4. *Use contents here*
5. Decrementing the reference count of each pointer
6. Freeing the space

At the C level, allocating a few KB of RAM and incrementing/decrementing a few thousand integers is pretty trivial relative to the overhead of the interpreter itself (keep in mind, no matter what you do, the reference count updates will occur as you loop and store each element in a named variable); just about anything you'd *do* with the resulting `list` will be more costly than the cost of creating and destroying it, especially if the slice is small (where the interpreter overhead of *anything* you might replace it with outweighs the cost of the slice).

If the copy really is a problem, and the `start` index is non-trivial (so `islice`'s inability to skip to the `start` point directly makes it non-viable, and the slice is large enough that you legitimately worry about memory), the most Pythonic approach I know of is basically just the example loop you provided:

```
for i in xrange(start, end):
    item = array[i]
    # do something with the item
```

If that's too slow (repeated indexing involves a surprising amount of interpreter overhead in the CPython reference interpreter), the most Pythonic alternative is to just push the indexing to the C layer:

```
from future_builtins import map  # Only needed on Python 2 to get Py3 generator based map

for item in map(array.__getitem__, xrange(start, end)):  # range on Python 3
    # do something with the item
```

This avoids the temporary `list`, in exchange for a higher per element cost (because the indexing can't be avoided completely, just hidden at the C layer with no byte code execution involved). Definitely less Pythonic though (`map` is generally frowned upon, and explicit references to special methods like `__getitem__` are extra ugly).